# Cannot save a Panels flexible layout for reuse

Tags: drupal

I wanted to save a flexible layout that I've already customized so that I can use it on the other pages on my site. After hitting the save button, I get a pop up with the following message:

> Unable to complete operation. Fatal
>   error in
>   modules_dir/panels/plugins/layouts/flexible/flexible.inc
>   on line 1741: Call to undefined
>   function ctools_export_crud_load()

Versions

- Drupal 6.17
- Panels 6.x-3.7 C
- Ctools 6.x-1.7

Any idea what I might have done wrong during the installation? or anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the following snippet of code before the line in question above to fix the problem in saving the flexible layout:

```
ctools_include('export');
```

Kudos to merlinofchaos for helping me out [here](http://drupal.org/node/890086).

But the question still hasn't been really answered as to why I encountered the said error.